# Why Master Page does not have OnInitComplete event?

Tags: asp.net

Why Master pages is not required to confirm the initialization completion ?

Although, Master Page can have controls and need initialization and like in content page, confirmation comes in Init-Complete event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InitComplete is not fired when the child controls of a control finish initialization, but when all the controls on the page are done.

The MasterPage being a control itself, loaded in the page, cannot detect by itself when all the other controls have completed initialization.

If any control, including the master page needs to know when the page initialization is over, it could subscribe to the [InitComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initcomplete%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event of the Page.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.InitComplete += Page_InitComplete;
    }

    void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //initialization complete
        //take necessary action
    }
```